# Atmega32u - Ground in bus powered configuration

Tags: power, usb, avr, atmega32u4

The Datasheet provides an example configuration for when the device is powered from the bus, and shows the bus `Vss` connected to `UGND` on the avr micro, but shows a connection to earth/ground on the other `GND` pins. Where is this ground coming from/connected to? The usb shield connection? Tied to bus' `Vss`?

[image: Example configuration]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the ground line on the USB cable, not the shield.  The UGND and GND are connected together on the board.  Here's an [example](https://www.arduino.cc/en/uploads/Main/arduino-lilypad-usb-schematic.pdf) of a schematic with Atmega32u4.

*p.s.*  If you would like to learn more about connecting the USB shield on the slave device side, see [this earlier question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/4515/how-to-connect-usb-connector-shield).